# uncheck all checkboxes from child component Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following problem: I have parent component with a list of checkboxes and two inputs. So when the any of those two inputs has been changed I need to uncheck all checkboxes. I would appreciate if you can help me to solve this.
I wanted to change `checkedItem` to trigger `watch` in child and then update all children, but it doesn't work.

### parent.vue

```
      <template>
        <div class="filter-item">
            <div class="filter-checkbox" v-for="item in filter.items">
                <checkbox :item="item" v-model="checkedItem"> {{ item }} </checkbox>
            </div>
            <div class="filter-range">
                <input v-model.number="valueFrom">
                <input v-model.number="valueTo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
<script>
    import checkbox from '../checkbox.vue'

    export default {
        props: ['filter'],
        data() {
            return {
                checkedItem: false,
                checkedItems: [],
                valueFrom: '',
                valueTo: '',
            }
        },
    watch: {
        'checkedItem': function () {},
        'valueFrom': function () {},
        'valueTo': function () {}
    },
    components: {checkbox}
}
</script>
```

### child.vue

```
<template>
    <label>
        <input :value="value" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)" v-model="checked" class="checkbox"
               type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkbox-faux"></span>
        <slot></slot>
    </label>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                checked: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateValue: function (value) {
                let item = this.item
                let checked = this.checked
                this.$emit('input', {item, checked})
            }
        },

        watch: {
            'checked': function () {
                this.updateValue()
            },
        },

        created: function () {
            this.checked = this.value
        },

        props: ['checkedItem', 'item']
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm new to Vuejs but the way I see it, the 'checked' watch just calls the updateValue function, however it doesn't return any value

Comment: How about changing the `checkedItem` to `checkedItem = []`. Does it work ?

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter, no, it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

When your `v-for` renders in the parent component, all the rendered `filter.items` are bound to the same `checkedItem` v-model.

To correct this, you would need to do something like this:

```
<div class="filter-checkbox" v-for="(item, index) in filter.items">
    <checkbox :item="item" v-model="item[index]> {{ item }} </checkbox>
</div>
```

To address your other issue, updating the child component list is as easy as updating `filter.items`.

You don't even need a watcher if you dont want to use one. Here is an alternative:

```
<input v-model.number="valueFrom" @keypress="updateFilterItems()">
```

And then:

```
methods: {
    updateFilterItems () {
        // Use map() or loop through the items
        // and uncheck them all.
    }
}
```

Always ask yourself twice if `watch` is necessary. It can create complexity unnecessarily.

Comment: but I didn't provide all information. I need to use checkboxes in the way that when you click on any the value should display in those inputs. 
I'm new to JS and Vue, so perhaps I don't understand how it should be implemented well.
And sorry, but I don't see how can method updateFilterItems() help. If I will make an array with items I should watch them all to see the updates? what if filter contains 1000 items?